# How to get rid of this "Cannot download the "Shortcodes" extension zip. No working transports found"?

Tags: wordpress

While during install the plugin, I am getting below error:

```
Cannot download the "Shortcodes" extension zip. No working transports found
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hosting issue and usually it means that the server has no OpenSSL module for PHP installed or the CURL module is outdated. Contact your hosting for this issue, it's probably not something you can fix yourself unless you own the server.